# Two buttons in a form with different functions

Tags: php

I just wanna ask how can I make a form with two buttons that do different functions? Like for example: I have this table with checkboxes and when a checkbox was checked and a certain button was clicked, the button will perform its assigned task.

Button1 can add, button2 can delete.

Can you help me again, please? I'm kind of new at this and I really want to know. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more of a JavaScript question than PHP.

You'll need to add an `onclick` to your buttons:

```
<input type="button" onclick="functionA();" value="button a" />
<input type="button" onclick="functionB();" value="button b" />
```

Then create these functions in JavaScript:

```
function functionA()
{
    // do stuff
    alert("add");
}

function functionB()
{
    // do stuff
    alert("delete");
}
```

---

Here's a basic example of where you can stick your JavaScript etc:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
        <title>Example</title>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function functionA()
            {
                 // do stuff
                 alert("add");
            }

            function functionB()
            {
                 // do stuff
                 alert("delete");
            }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <input type="button" onclick="functionA();" value="button a" />
        <input type="button" onclick="functionB();" value="button b" />
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do I need to have a separate php page when I have to make a function like that?

Comment: No, you can either put the JavaScript between a script tag in the head, or load in an external .js file in the head.

Comment: Can you give me an example, please? I'm so sorry for causing a trouble. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking at a server side solution, you can have two submit buttons in the form with different name attributes and then check the `$_GET['buttonName']` or `$_POST['buttonName']` variables depending on your form submission method.

For example:

```
<form action="action.php" method="post">
   <input type="text"....blah blah />
   ....
   <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" />
   <input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete" />
</form>
```

Comment: THen I'll use the the if method and specify there what the functions these buttons will perform? Am I correct?